# React life cycle methods (functional components)

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I'm a newbie to react.js and i don't know class components.I'm trying hard to understand the react life cycle.

Comment: I recommend the [react docs beta](https://beta.reactjs.org/), it's way better and the examples use functional components and hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need info on React life cycle methods for class components, check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

If you need info on React functional components check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html